# Create new set of aliases based on current set of aliases (eg. gst -> dst)?

Tags: zsh, git, alias, oh-my-zsh

I'm using git aliases from zsh plugins: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git

So it has git aliases like:

```bsh
gst # git status
ga # git add
gc "commit" # git commit -v "commit"
...
```

...and I'm also using git bare repo to backup all my dotfiles: https://github.com/Anthonyive/dotfiles/blob/0706bc81daa3aeb7899b506cd89d4ab78fc7b176/USAGE.md

In particular, the git bare repo technique aliases the git command to `dotfiles`:

```bsh
alias dotfiles='git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'
alias d='dotfiles'
```

So then how do I map the all the git alias command to `d`? Like:

```bsh
dst # similar to gst, but uses the dotfiles alias
da # similar to ga
dc "commit" # similar to gc "commit"
...
```

Mapping them one by one seems very tedious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associative array [`aliases`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-aliases) contains all alias definitions.

```
for name in "${(@k)aliases}"; do
  if [[ $name == g* && $aliases[$name] == 'git '* ]]; then
    alias d${name#g}="dotfiles ${aliases[$name]#git }"
  fi
done
```

Alternatively, you could change the `d` alias to a function that expects a following git command, but first expands shell aliases and removes any leading `git`.

```
alias d='d ' # expand aliases after d
function d {
  if [[ $1 == "git" ]]; then shift; fi
  dotfiles "$@"
}
```

Then `d gst` will run `dotfiles status`, `d gc myfile` will run `dotfiles commit myfile`, `d ls-tree` will run `dotfiles ls-tree`, etc. Completion is doable but not easily.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly! Btw, you have a little typo where you missed a '{' in front of `alias` in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

To replace all calls to `git` with `git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME`, you can use a function:

```bsh
git() {
  command git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME "$@"
}
```

*However,* you don’t actually have to do that for this case. Instead of passing those option flags to `git`, you can just specify them through environment variables instead:

```bsh
export GIT_DIR=$HOME/.dotfiles/
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME
```

See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt

---

As an aside, instead of maintaining and trying to remember a large amount of aliases, you could instead just use [`zsh-autocomplete`’s history completion mode](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete). (Disclaimer: I’m the maintainer of this plugin.)

[image]

Comment: You seem to be the developer of `zsh-autocomplete`. If that's the case, please disclose that when advertising it.

Comment: Fair enough. Added.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this overwrites all my git commands? What I want is to map all `dotfiles` to `git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME`, then alias commands like `dotfiles status` to `dst`. However, I want to keep `git` as is.